# How to put image and two lines of text vertically and wrap them when they don't fit on the same row (when in mobile)

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm creating a small site that I want to keep its design in the tablet/mobile version as well. This is what I have:

[Jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/cekmtooo/1/)

This is what I want:

[image]

Centered - in the middle of the page:

And when I resize the window the image and text to resize as well, and when they cannot fit on the same line to go like this:
[image]

I managed to do something similar but when i resize the window the image and text goes one over the other and then the text goes on the 2nd row.

Code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="row">
  <div class=" s12 m4 l3">
    <img src = "http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/jN9tX6dCJ6_XL9E4K1KCO2Tuwe9_rYUbwv723eu6XGI0PWGLcPs0259VscOu249PPKKcU5AOXrq6JnleEaoK6K_JvZ2PY9lw3pMApzOpTQ=s660" height="111" width="300"/>
  </div>
  
  <div class=" s12 m4 l3">
    <h4> This is an example of, <br> image and text on the same line </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

I followed what other people suggested in other posts, but their suggestion messed up my design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsbin.com/cavuracegu/1/edit?html,css,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>


<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12" style="display: table;position: absolute;height: 100%;width: 100%;">
<div style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
    <img style="display: inline-block" src = "http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/jN9tX6dCJ6_XL9E4K1KCO2Tuwe9_rYUbwv723eu6XGI0PWGLcPs0259VscOu249PPKKcU5AOXrq6JnleEaoK6K_JvZ2PY9lw3pMApzOpTQ=s660" width="50%"/>
      <h4 class="text" style="width: 45%;display: inline-block;word-wrap:break-word;"> This is an example of, image and text on the same line </h4>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .text {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}


  .text {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Is it possible without bootstrap? I already loaded materialize and they might conflict.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use materialize.

Comment: I managed to include bootstrap, the problem is that bellow the image with the text I get a lot of white space, the equivalent of like 5 <br>, how can I delete that? So between the image and text and another element that I put in my HTML is a lot of space.

Comment: In this example there are display: table and display:table-cell in style for vertical middle alignment. Maybe you need to remove this styles? I don't understand you clearly.

Comment: Also there "height: 100%;" Try to reduce this procent.

Comment: Use chrome dev console to pick html and css elements and view html/css structure of the page. You'l see why page looks as it looks.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed it. One more thing, hopefully I'm not too annoying, when both picture and text cannot fit on the same row (when I resize the width of the browser), the picture and text seems to be aligned to the left, can they both be centered on the middle of the page only in that scenario?

Comment: In my browser picture and text are on the same row. Only if screen <~100px text is under image but it is not critically. But I made small changes in script. https://jsbin.com/peqirutowo/edit?html,css,output - added left: 5% for absolute pisitioning of the full block (it is more clear, you can experiment with this value if you have another image) and text-align:center for text. If you need you may apply these changes. Also you may use media queries to set text font size for small screen for better text  block height.

Comment: Also your image has a white padding at the left - if you need you may use gimp or other tool for cutting the image

Answer (score 2):

The final code (tested on JsFiddle):

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 780px){

:not(h4){
    text-align: center;
}


body .s12{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 0%;
    text-align: left;
}

#div1{
    margin-top: 20%;
}

}



:not(h4){
     text-align: center; 
}


.s12{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 20%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="row">
  <div class=" s12 m4 l3" id="div1">
    <img src = "http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/jN9tX6dCJ6_XL9E4K1KCO2Tuwe9_rYUbwv723eu6XGI0PWGLcPs0259VscOu249PPKKcU5AOXrq6JnleEaoK6K_JvZ2PY9lw3pMApzOpTQ=s660" height="111" width="300"/>
  </div>
  
  <div class=" s12 m4 l3" id="div2">
    <h4> This is an example of image, <br> with text on the same line </h4>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, both lines of the text should be aligned. In your solution one is centered and the other one is more to the left.

Comment: A bit more to the left? Can have a look anyway?

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width: 780px) messes up the sublevels of my navbar, is there any workaround? Thank you!